# How to remove a specific key from Firebase in Swift 3

Tags: swift, uitableview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How can I get the marked key then remove it from `UITableView` swift 3 ?

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete {

            self.grocery.remove(at: indexPath.row)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
        }
    }
```

[image: Please refer this image.]

Comment: I think all you need is to update your table after you deleted an item from source array

Answer (score 0):

To remove you can simply set the value as nil to remove it from firebase. After you've called the remove function then make sure to remove the row from the tableView.

```
func removeObjectFromFireBase(userKey: String, removeThisGrocery: String) {
    let ref = Database.database().reference()
    let groceryRef = ref.child("Users").child(userKey).child("Grocery")
    groceryRef.child(removeThisObject).setValue(nil)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]? {
    let deleteAction = UITableViewRowAction(style: .destructive, title: "DELETE") { (rowAction, indexPath) in

        //Call the removeFromFirebase function with the required parameters
        removeObjectFromFirebase(userKey: userKey, removeThisGrocery: groceryKey)
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }

    deleteAction.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    return [deleteAction, addAction]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove any data from Firebase as following:

```
let ref = Database.database().reference()
let groceryRef = ref.child("Users").child(userKey).child("Grocery")
groceryRef.removeValue()
```